# Moving cross-hairs/drawing objects using Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need some ideas on how I can achieve the following in WPF:

1. Draw "n" number of cross-hairs or other drawing objects onto a Canvas. I am not specifically referring to WPF Canvas, but it could be that. The value "n" is coming from Binding. I would like to know on what someone would use for this canvas that can add drawing objects during runtime based on binding.
2. Move appropriate cross-hair/drawing based on the respective position data value. The position values will come from Binding as well. The position value could update at a high-speed, so the movement has to be a smooth animation. I would have started using the top/left co-ordinates to achieve this, but I've heard something about Render Transformations, that are performed on the GPU vs CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ItemsControl` in the View with `DataTemplates`, and a `Collection` on the View Model side. Used `TranslateTransform` in the `DataTemplate` style  to move the drawing objects.